# How to get process in client side when upload image using multipart

Tags: java, android, apache, file-upload

I'm working on a project that needs to upload image using Multipart. 
Here is my code:

```
public void doUploadGIF(File image) {

        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "myurl");
            MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            multipartEntity.addPart("gif", new FileBody(image));
            httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

            mHttpClient.execute(httppost, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Time for uploading:"
                    + String.valueOf(end - start));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Upload", "Error while uploading");
        }
    }

private class PhotoUploadResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<Object> {

        @Override
        public Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity); 
            Log.d("UPLOAD", responseString);

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Now in client side (Android) I let the user know the process of uploading ( percent ).
How can I do that?
Thanks for your attention !

Comment: Use Asynctask and in `onProgressUpdate` you can update the progress bar or whatever you going to update during the upload

Comment: I know, But the problem is how can I know that how many percent the file is uploaded ?

Answer (score 0):

in my case I used the file size in KB and set the limit of the progressbar with the file size in KB. and for updating the progressbar I used :

```
int bufferLength = 1024;

File file = new File(ImgURI);
mFileLen =  file.length();

int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i +=bufferLength) {
    progress = i/1024;
    progressBar1.setMax(kbfilesize);
    publishProgress(progress);
}
```

Comment: I think there's a little confuse here.
My file'length is 2MB. How can I know how many length the server received in a specific time?